# Getting date recorded data from mp3 file?

Tags: mp3, audio-recording, id3, audio, soundcloud

Is it possible to extract date recorded from mp3 files? Are there any audio recorders which embed this data?

Is the file's "date created" field changed during an http upload?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.ibiblio.org/mp3info/ (manpage at http://www.ibiblio.org/mp3info/mp3info.html). Alternatively http://www.mutschler.de/mp3ext/ has more of a UI.